# Wildcard support for doorkeeper redirect URIs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, doorkeeper

I have a Ruby on Rails application using Oauth 2.0 implemented using the **doorkeeper** gem (1.3.0).

I am trying to set up a wildcard redirect uri (e.g., `http://*.mydomain.com/redirected`). However, this doesn't seem to be possible. In the doorkeeper-mounted route `/oauth/applications`, if I type in a wildcard url it says `Must be a valid uri.`

Is there a configuration or way to patch doorkeeper in order to get this functionality? I need the * wildcard to pass validation during the registration of a new application and *also* need it to work at the client authorization endpoint.

Comment: Did you arrive at a solution? I am facing this issue as well, and hard-coding each callback is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this too, thought about it for a while then checked the specification. This would be a direct violation of the specification of Oauth.

> 3.1.2.  Redirection Endpoint
>
> After completing its interaction with the resource owner, the
> authorization server directs the resource owner's user-agent back to
> the client.  The authorization server redirects the user-agent to the
> client's redirection endpoint previously established with the
> authorization server during the client registration process or when
> making the authorization request.
>
> The redirection endpoint URI MUST be an absolute URI as defined by
> [RFC3986] Section 4.3.  The endpoint URI MAY include an
> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" formatted (per Appendix B) query
> component ([RFC3986] Section 3.4), which MUST be retained when adding
> additional query parameters.  The endpoint URI MUST NOT include a
> fragment component.

[Source](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.1.2)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like support for wildcard *Redirect URIs* was removed in [Doorkeeper 2.1.1](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/blob/master/NEWS.md#211---2015-02-06).

You can see some reasoning in this commit:
https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/commit/fd57c475f4fb954faa62d7973d6c8382b5b6401f

And some further discussion here:
https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/pull/437